# Virtual Machine and/or emulator for Android

Tags: linux, android, virtual-machine, emulator

I'd prefer something that's complete and will run arbitrary android apps in the same environment as an actual device, in return for whatever additional resource requirements the VM consumes.

Or an emulator. It should run on linux.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: Do you need it to run __on__ android or some/any other platform?

Comment: @SteveBarnes on linux

Comment: What's wrong with the official one provided by Google?

Comment: @Gilles some apps (.apk) are incompatible with the emulator

Comment: Which ones? These apps are likely to be unable to run on some physical devices too. Are they incompatible because they require some special hardware? Do they try to detect the emulator and refuse to run?

Answer (score 2):

[Android Developer Studio & SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) include [virtual machines](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html)/[emulators](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) that allow you to test your code for various editions of android and various hardware as well as on the actual device.

- It runs on Windows/OS-X and Linux.
- Free

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)** is another Android emulator alternative you can choose.

Like Android emulator that has been mentioned before, Genymotion allows you to test and run your Android apps. It is fast, simple, and powerful. Genymotion is **basically free**. But, it depends on how many features you want to get. You can learn the comparison between free and paid [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/store).

Beside that, Genymotion is available for **Linux** machine. The **requirements** of machine are:

- 2 GB of RAM
- 400 MB disk space
- VT-X/AMD-v capable CPU
- Recent OpenGL 2.0 GPU

Currently, I am developing an apps for mobile device. I always use Android Virtual Device, part of Android SDK, to test and run the code instead of Genymotion. I have read some sources that Genymotion is faster than Android Virtual Device. So, give a try! and I would recommend to learn more this product [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/product).